# service element missing for the invoke element in deploy.xml

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

I recently started learning WSO to provide a open source option for BPM customers.

I however am stuck. I followed the [BPEL Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS351/BPEL+Guide) and still getting the same error. It fails to deploy the Process for the reason "service element missing for the invoke element in deploy.xml" Can anyone please provide some assistance.

I followed each step very carefully and even retried all the steps 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be the same as you have declared - "service element missing for the invoke element in deploy.xml". Just check the deploy.xml file related to your bpel process. In there is there a  element with a related value in the  element in  element? It should be missing there, while in the configuration steps. It should be in the following format.

```
<process name="EnrollmentProcess:EnrollmentProcess">
    ...
    .....
    <invoke partnerLink="EPL">
      <service name="EnrollmentService:EnrollmentService"  port="EnrollmentServiceSOAP"/>
    </invoke>
     ...
    ....
</process>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the invoke tag in the deploy.xml:

```
...
<invoke partnerLink="client" />
...
```

That worked on me.